# How to implement like search in encrypted column JPA specification

Tags: hibernate, encryption, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have an entity A having following column definition:

```
@Column(name = "project_address", nullable = false, length = 500)
@Convert(converter = EncodeDecodeAttribute.class)
private String projectAddress;
```

EncodeDecodeAttribute.class:

```
public class EncodeDecodeAttribute implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {
            ...
            @Override
            public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String s) {
                try {
                    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(s))
                        return s;
                    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptCipher.doFinal(s.getBytes()));
                } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
                    log.error("Error convert to database column for value {} with msg {}",s,e);
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
                }
            }
            
            @Override
            public String convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
                try {
                    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(s))
                        return s;
                    return new String(decryptCipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(s)));
                } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
                    log.error("Error convert to entity attribute for value {} with msg {}",s,e);
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
                }
            }
    }
```

Now I want to implement like clause (wildcards) and case insensitive search on the column projectAddress.

How to achieve this ?

Below is my current code where its working for exact match only.

```
public static Specification<A> applyProjectAddressLike(String projectAddress) {
    return ((root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) ->
            Objects.nonNull(projectAddress) ?
                    criteriaBuilder.like(root.get(A_.projectAddress), projectAddress) :
                    criteriaBuilder.and()
    );
```

Now if i pass "ABC%" or "%ABC" as projectAddress then the whole word(including %) will encrypted and then JPA will run the query, hence getting no matching results.

Appreciate you help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

encrypted columns are not indexed and not meant to be seen.
but still depends on your requirement it can be searched (but not with JPA) you can do it with JQL.
there are various of ways to search through them, for example have another column that will contain a hash of the name that was encrypted but then  you will be able to search only the whole text. and searching "ILIKE" is a more complexed as mentioned here:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23908/how-to-search-a-mysql-database-with-encrypted-fields
in my project I needed to search with "ILIKE %something%". implementing a tree is too complex for my use case. The way I implemented this was to run an SQL/JQL query from the java like so:

```js
String sqlQueryFindUsersByLastName = "select u.* from Users u where CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(u.lastName, :hashedSecretPhrases) using utf8) like :lastName"

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

List<UsersEntity> userEntities = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
            sqlQueryFindUsersByLastName, UsersEntity.class)
        .setParameter("hashedSecretPhrases", AttributeEncryptorConverter.unHexedHash)
        .setParameter("lastName", "%" + lastName + "%")
        .getResultList();
```

in order to be performance wise use hashedSecretPhrases as byte[].
it is much faster if you do it once in your java and send it to the database instead of letting the DB to do it for you for every row (like AES_DECRYPT('u.lastName', UNHEX(MD5('some key')))).
Same is correct about every other functionality that you want, for example LOWER, keep the sql phrase as simple as you can without manipulations..
of-course that you need to take into account that CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT will take more time than querying on regular indexed column, so this solution depends on your use case. if it doesn't fit your use case then read the link i attached and implement it the way it fits best.